# getCurrentPosition does not execute on Android from Trigger Toolkit

Tags: trigger.io

I'm trying to get the user's current position using forge.geolocation.getCurrentPosition. I have the module enabled in my code, I have my device's GPS and mobile data turned on, and I'm running the code on my Android device from Trigger Toolkit.

When I do this, it appears that forge.geolocation.getCurrentPosition never executes. Neither the success or fail callback function are reached (the first command in each is a log message). Nor are any errors thrown.

However, when I package my app as an apk and install it on my device, the exact same code works just fine.

Any ideas why this isn't executing on Android via Trigger Toolkit, or how I can go about debugging this?

Comment: It appears eventually the coordinates do return from the call, but it takes several minutes for the coordinates to return when running with Forge. Anyone know how to speed this up, or remove whatever bottleneck is slowing it down?

Comment: On Android, we just pass the call straight through to navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition - try calling that directly?

Comment: Had this same problem and got around it by setting the "timeout" property of the options object. This at least forces the fail callback if no location returned and/or it's slow returning

Comment: Is this "timeout" property documented somewhere?